# Multiple Choice - predefined answers in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

Is there a way to give the user a predefined answer such as *yes/no*. For example, if I ask my user: *Are you happy?* I want to let him choose from: *Yes/No*.

So he doesn't have to write any word but clicking on *Yes* or *No* options.

Comment: hi, can you tell for which platform you want to give buttons to clicked ?

Comment: Hi, i only want to use dialogflow in an own app. I dont´t want to integrate this with facebook messanger, slack, telegram or any other plattform. If i would use such a plattform, i´m able to integrate a quick response. But i only want to use dialogflow in my own app. Thanks for the help

Comment: Dialogflow doesn't seem to support buttons out of the box unless you design for a supported platform.

Have you looked into the custom payloads? https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom_payload
With this you could try to render a button in your own app.

Comment: you can create your own widget with some web technology knowledge,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1HDNrVNNnQ